# window.getSelection() deleteFromDocument for list item

Tags: javascript, selection

My html code is

```
 <ul>
    <li>list1</li>
    <li>list2</li>
    <li>list3</li>
    <li>list4</li>
    <li>list5</li>
  </ul>
```

when i select the first three list items and using the following code to delete the selected list items

[image]

```
 sel = window.getSelection();
    if(!sel.isCollapsed){
        sel.deleteFromDocument();
    }
```

its looks like the following

[image]

how to delete the selected lists with bulletins,

Comment: Are you also able to select `<li>` tags to delete in the selection?

Comment: @MKB, i cant able to select the first <li> tag where i start selecting

Answer (score 1):

As I can see , you're using plain Javascript, so instead of applying the `sel.deleteFromDocument();` use `sel.focusNode.parentNode.remove()`.

**NOTE:** This is suggested if you're intending the deletion for the list items only.

Check the below example.

```js
document.onmouseup = onSelect;
document.onkeyup = onSelect;

function onSelect() {
  sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
    sel.focusNode.parentNode.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list1</li>
  <li>list2</li>
  <li>list3</li>
  <li>list4</li>
  <li>list5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please select from top to bottom and then click the canvas around it, its pretty buggy.

Comment: Please re-check the example @Randy :)

Comment: I've reverted back to the earlier edit because it is getting more complicated. I think there's no other way to get this done by plain javascript.

Comment: `sel.focusNode.parentNode.remove()`did the job for me. I wanted to remove not only the node text but also the node itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty list elements:

```js
$('ul li').filter(function() {return $(this).text() == '';}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
  
  <li></li>
  <li>a</li>
  
</ul>
```